# JAXB : Doesn't there is need of XMl attribute names to be matched with java Annotations in JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am working on a existing Application which is using JAXB .

Currently there is a unmarshell process that will happen on a XML document

For example this is the xml document

```
String str = "<BACS xmlns=\"http://www.bacs.org/BACS\"><Bahut  number=\"1234\"><Order Quantity=\"1\" ><Bag value=\"1\" /></Order></Bahut><BACS>";


public class One{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "numberDT")
    protected String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "valueDT")
    protected String src;
```

My question is , that in our Application the XML attribute names and the names in the java annotations doesn't match ?? But still the code is working .

Please let me know , if i am missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) metadata needs to match the XML for the unmarshalling to be successful.  In your use case there could be several possibilities for the behaviour your are seeing.

1. The source you are looking at may not correspond to the classes being used when you run your application.  You may want to double check your classpath.
2. The problematic class may be mapped with an `XmlAdapter`.  An `XmlAdapter` is a mechanism where your domain object can be converted, and the result of the conversion is what is mapped to XML.  This would mean the annotations on your domain object are not used.  Check for the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation on the field, property, type, or package level:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter
3. If you are using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) the metadata may be supplied via and XML document, this XML document can be used to override or replace metadata supplied via annotations:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html